# Android menu icons - not all visible?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu

please help me,
why some icons are not displayed on the menu? How to make so that all the icons are visible? On the pictures I painted my menu.

[image]

[image]

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item //this icon is visible
        android:id="@+id/action_add_new_group"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_add_group"
        android:title="@string/action_add_new_group"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item //this icon is visible
        android:id="@+id/action_load_from_sd"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_add_dictionary"
        android:title="@string/action_load_from_sd"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item //this icon is NOT visible
        android:id="@+id/action_convert_from_xls"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_date_sorting"
        android:title="@string/action_convert_from_xls"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item //this icon is NOT visible
        android:id="@+id/action_sortting_options"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_date_sorting"
        android:title="sorting"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
        <menu>
            <item //this icon is visible
                android:id="@+id/action_sort_by_date"
                android:icon="@drawable/menu_date_sorting"
                android:title="by date"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all the icons, you should put `app:showAsAction` as `always` instead of `ifRoom|withText` in your menu `item`s.

Comment: I tried. It does not work! It may even have some ideas why not work for the first level menu? Not only works for the first level menu.

Comment: May be you don't have enough space in your ActionBar. Try setting a smaller title or something.

Comment: No, I too tested it. An icon with a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

only icon means,

```
android:icon="@drawable/menu_date_sorting"
android:title="sorting"
app:showAsAction="always"
```

icon with Text means,

```
android:icon="@drawable/menu_date_sorting"
android:title="sorting"
app:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

Comment: I tried. It does not work! It may even have some ideas why not work for the first level menu? Not only works for the first level menu.

Answer (score 0):

The icons of the menu items whose app:showAsAction="always" will be shown in the action bar. But all the other menu items will not have an icon when inside the OptionsMenu.

If you set showAsAction attribute to always that menu icon will be shown in the actionbar at all times.

Comment: I tried. It does not work! It may even have some ideas why not work for the first level menu? Not only works for the first level menu.

Comment: Try to test the app in a tab. You will see that the items you have set as showAsAction="always", will show up in the actionBar. When in your phone the icon will show only if there is room in actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change this line of code `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` to `app:showAsAction="always|withText"` When you add `ifRoom`, the menu item is only visible if there is enough room for the item to be displayed. And the `always` as the name suggests, it will always be shown in the menu.